# Google maps api v2 stopped working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Long ago I've setup a Google Maps project using the old API version(v2). I know Google Maps API v2 is being deprecated and I'm working on rewriting it for the new version, but I need this working until then.

Suddenly, the map stopped working throwing this error in an alert box:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. This
>   site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client ID provided. If
>   you are the owner of this application, you can learn more about
>   registering URLs here:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/guide.html#URLs

I haven't changed anything in the current app and the requests per day are less than 1000(way far from the daily quota). The first thing I've noticed is that there was no allowed referrers specified. But even after they was set to(replacing sitename.com with my domain):

```
sitename.com
sitename.com/*
www.sitename.com
www.sitename.com/*
*.sitename.com
*.sitename.com/*
```

There was no result whatsoever even after couple of hours. The reason why this application suddenly stopped working is still a mystery to me (once again - nothing has been changed in my code or the google account), but most importantly I need really fast solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try re-generate another key? Even if the error still continue after swapping to new key, you might need to contact Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using v2.x. There was a release of v2 very recently.  If you aren't using v2.s; you might try that (or v=2) to see if it resolves your problem (for now, they have gone to a 2 week upgrade cycle on v2: "We have updated v=2.x to 2.441. v=2 will be updated in 2 weeks and v=2.s will be updated in 4 weeks.")

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile [creating an issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v2%20-%20Regression) on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) that documents your issue (preferably with an example, doesn't have to be your live site, but a jsfiddle or a simple demo) that will let the Google Maps API team fix it before the broken version goes all the way to v2.s, it would be good if they knew about the issue before the two week upgrade.

Comment: But you didn't provide enough information for them to address the problem (a live example or an attachment that exhibits the problem).  At this point it looks like the working theory is that you were not loading the API as required by the terms of use.  [issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4607)

Comment: The [issue you opened](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4607) was closed. It looks like you'd saved and were serving some old API JS alongside the real API, and the two were incompatible.